# Access to own private constructors via derived class constructor inheritance

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, crtp, inheriting-constructors

[Consider](https://godbolt.org/z/Wx5YKh):

```
struct B {
    void f();
private:
    B(int, int = 0);
};
struct D : B { using B::B; };
void B::f() {
    auto a = D{0};
    auto b = D(0);
    auto c = D(0, 0);
    D x{0};
    D y(0);
    D z(0, 0);
}
```

GCC accepts (since 7.1; previously rejects all).
Clang accepts `b` and `xyz` but rejects `a` and `c`.
MSVC rejects all in C++14 mode but accepts all in C++17 mode.

Which compiler(s) are correct? Did the rules change between C++14 and C++17 - if so, why in C++14 is `B::f` not allowed to access its own constructors (named via `D`)? And why does Clang only accept the (function-style) cast at `b` and not list-initialization at `a` or constructor call at `c`?

(Making `B` a `friend` of `D` makes Clang accept, except for older versions (3.8 and older), and MSVC in C++14 mode. It doesn't make a difference to gcc.)

Now, I know that [C++14 says](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/class.inhctor#4):

> A constructor so declared [as an inheriting constructor] has the same access as the corresponding constructor in [the base class] X.

And in C++17 the rules were simplified, clarified and [moved to [namespace.udecl]](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.udecl#19):

> A using-declarator that names a constructor does not create a synonym; instead, the additional constructors are accessible if they would be accessible when used to construct an object of the corresponding base class, and the accessibility of the using-declaration is ignored.

So, I thought that perhaps "has the same access as" means the inherited constructors are `private` to `D` so only accessible to `D` (and its friends), rather than `private` to `B` (and so accessible to `B::f`) as are their corresponding constructors in `B`. But under that interpretation, one would be able to subvert access checking and access private constructors of one's base class by inheriting them. So surely in C++14 the intent of the wording is the same as expressed more clearly in C++17 - but then why does MSVC change its behavior depending on language version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a [lot of issues](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration#Notes) with the original specification of inheriting constructors (as they were then called), several of which involved access control.  They were [fixed retroactively](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0136r1.html), which is supposed to be official for C++14 only (as the most recently published standard at the time).  Many compilers **choose** to apply such changes to even earlier versions where it makes sense (*i.e.*, C++11).

However, it wasn’t possible to access private base-class constructors even in C++14 as published, because the implicit definition of an inheriting private constructor would **fail** to invoke the actual private constructor in the base.  MSVC is therefore correct except for not applying the defect report to C++14; Clang appears to have a separate bug in handling certain kinds of initialization; perhaps it accepts `D(0)` because it’s defined in terms of `D …(0);`.  Current GCC is correct in all cases.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense. Filed https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=48545 .

Comment: And clang is now fixed (on main) by https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/commit/d5d8c529abe65ce55c24b0333842bb31746a8bf8